# Steam API, checking if backpack is full

Tags: python, steam-web-api

Is it possible with steamAPI to check player's slots count? I want to check if tf2's backpack is full. Could not find anything like that in API, but some websites are tracking slots count.

Answer (score 0):

Just found it. https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/WebAPI/GetPlayerItems
'num_backpack_slots'